# CSS transition is under an element with position realative or absolute

Tags: css

Why when you set an element to position relative or absolute, elements with transition are under this element, but when delete position property it's in front?

http://jsfiddle.net/yfvbeLct/1/

HTML:

```
<div class='square'></div>
<div class='text'>Text here</div>
```

CSS:

```
.square {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    transition: all 0.5s 0.1s linear;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.square:hover {
    margin-top: -50px;
}
.text {
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't forget to set `z-index` property to your styles when u decide to declare `position`.

Try for example `z-index:10` for your `.square` box. Here is working demo - [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yfvbeLct/3/)

Here is good tutorial to learn how it works - [Stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context)